# cannot access private member declared in class while using protected and inheritance

Tags: c++, variables, inheritance, member, protected

I have some problem while using `protected` member. Relevant codes and the error I get is below. The classes have all the needed functions and variables. I have just summarized the relevant parts. What should I do ?

MFS.h:

```
class MFS
{
protected:
    MatrixXd commandedLateral;
};
```

CSimulator.h:

```
class CSimulator : MFS
{
};
```

CSimulator.cpp:

```
void CSimulator::calculateActuator(MFS* mfs)
{
    actuator = -gain * mfs->commandedLateral(1,0);
}
```

Error C2248: 'MFS::commandedLateral' : cannot access private member declared in class 'MFS'

Answer (score 0):

[`protected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) members could be accessed only through the derived class, i.e. you can't access it through the base class `MFS`.

(emphasis mine)

> A protected member of a class is only accessible
>
> 1) to the members and friends of that class;
>
> 2) to the members `and friends (until C++17)` of any derived class of
>   that class, **but only when the class of the object through which the
>   protected member is accessed is that derived class or a derived class
>   of that derived class**:

For example the following code should work fine.

```
void CSimulator::calculateActuator(CSimulator* mfs)
{
    actuator = -gain * mfs->commandedLateral(1,0);
}
```